# Not able to get coverage for the code written inside viewAbilityConfigCallbackPairs in jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library, testing-libraryreact-native

I have basically written a code of flatlist and used `viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs` props. Divided UI code and business logic in separate file. Now the issue is I am trying to write testcase using jest for the same but it seems `viewAbilityConfigCallbackPairs` does gets called but `onViewableItemsChanged` not

Here is my code of component, business logic and testcase:

Component:

```
<FlatList
      testID="list"
      horizontal
      ref={scrollRef}
      getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
      snapToAlignment="start"
      decelerationRate={'fast'}
      viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs={
        viewAbilityConfigCallbackPairs.current
      }
      snapToInterval={width}
      // rest of the code
/>
```

custom hook:

```
const viewAbilityConfigCallbackPairs = useRef<ViewabilityConfigCallbackPair[]
>([{viewabilityConfig, onViewableItemsChanged}]);

const onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(
({viewableItems}: {viewableItems: Array<ViewToken>}) => {
  console.log('useCalendarScreen.ts 2023 viewableItems ',viewableItems);
  setCurrentDate(viewableItems?.[0]?.item);
  setCurrentIndex(viewableItems?.[0]?.index ?? 0);
},
[],
);
```

Testcase

```
test('Initial render test case', async () => {
    const {getByTestId} = render(<Component />);
})
```

Once I run this testcase, it calls other methods from custom hook and it even covers things from `viewAbilityConfigCallbackPairs`, but does not cover lines from `onViewableItemsChanged`, however ideally it should be called in first render.

Here is the screenshot of coverage

[image]